# How to convert pandas time series into numpy array of total elapsed time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pandas newbie here.
I want to convert a date range time series *date_time* from pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
In [1]: date_time = pd.date_range('2017/10/27','2017/10/29',freq='12H')
```

into a numpy array *t* containing the elapsed time (for instance, in hours), such that:

```
In [2]: t
Out[2]: array([0,12,24,36,48])
```

What would be the most direct way to do this?

I need this to pass the numpy array *t* to odeint routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [divide Timedeltas by another Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion) to convert them to a desired frequency unit (such as hours). Use the `.values` attribute to convert the result to a NumPy array:

```
In [37]: ((date_time - date_time[0]) / pd.Timedelta('1H')).values
Out[37]: array([  0.,  12.,  24.,  36.,  48.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could *also* convert to a `pd.Series` and call `dt.total_seconds`.

```
x = pd.Series(date_time)
y = (x - x[0]).dt.total_seconds().div(60 * 60).values
y

array([  0.,  12.,  24.,  36.,  48.])
```

Comment: Thanks! also useful. Now I'll know what to do when I have Series type as my input.